# Get PDO from PDOStatement

Tags: php, pdo

Consider the following:

```
$PDOStatement = $PDO->prepare($query);
```

Is it possible to get the `$PDO` instance from the `$PDOStatement` instance?

Comment: `var_dump($PDOStatement)` would show any back-links in the statement object.

Comment: The docs for [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) don't seem to show any way to do this.  May I ask *why* you want to do this?  What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: It's trivial. A class that I'm writing needs both a `PDOStatement` instance and the `PDO` instance that generated it. I was wondering if I could simplify the interface of the class.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can.

Comment: @raina77ow, you should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible. Even though each instance of PDOStatement stores a DB handle used to create it ([quoting lxr for PHP 5.6](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#542)):

```
/* represents a prepared statement */
543 struct _pdo_stmt_t {
544    /* these items must appear in this order at the beginning of the
545       struct so that this can be cast as a zend_object.  we need this
546       to allow the extending class to escape all the custom handlers
547       that PDO declares.
548    */
549    zend_object std;
550
...
572    /* we want to keep the dbh alive while we live, so we own a reference */
573    zval database_object_handle;
574    pdo_dbh_t *dbh;
```

... it's not exposed via public methods.

---

It might be worth of a note that `pdo_dbh_t` instances in turn may (at least it seems so) store references to `pdo_stmt_t` ([**link**](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#427)):

```
427 /* represents a connection to a database */
428 struct _pdo_dbh_t {
... 
501    /* when calling PDO::query(), we need to keep the error
502     * context from the statement around until we next clear it.
503     * This will allow us to report the correct error message
504     * when PDO::query() fails */
505    pdo_stmt_t *query_stmt;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this has changed in the past 8 years.  My case is that I have a library of functions in a class, among them one called pdoExecuteStatement(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data, int $flags).  One of the allowed flags is CLASSNAME::IGNORE_PDO_ERROR.  Now if that's set, I'd love to be able to execute $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERR_MODE, ...) but alas!  So we use TRY/CATCH. In an environment where multiple simultaneous PDO connections are commmon, this ability would be a great assistance